# What should I do to make UTF-8 vs ASCII strings equals?

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

code:

```
$utf8 = "32572_zał nr 13  wybór marszałka.pdf";
$target = "32572_za' nr 13  wybÆr marsza'ka.pdf";
var_dump($utf8 == $target)
```

I need to change string in $utf8 to bo equals $target.

What can I do in this case?

Something more advance than str_replace.

Comment: Why are they using different characters in the first place?

Comment: Those strings aren't the same... So you would have to translate the characters using `str_replace` or something else.

Comment: Check out iconv: http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php I've used it a lot for ASCII to UTF8 and vice-versa

Comment: I have bunch of files with bad encoding in file names. In db names are stored in UTF-8

Comment: The filenames look pretty botched. I don't think they're in any sort of valid encoding at all (the ł would never get mapped to '). Perhaps it's time to fix them up? Get a list of filenames from the database and a list from the filesystem, then use levenshtein() to see which file match closely with which database entry. The task is even easier if the numeric prefixes are unique.